# Installing dependencies with npm-peer-dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependencies

I am trying to install the required node_modules for a small project running Angular 11 using `npm install`

My goal is get the project to work locally after downloading it from GitHub. I have already installed the latest version of the Angular CLI.
After running the install command I tried `npm start`.

I was expecting that after running the install and start command to be able to run the project locally.
However the actual result I get after running the install command is the following list of errors:

```
> ng serve

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler'
Require stack:

\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js
\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js
\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js
\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\typescript.js
\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\index.js
\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

See "angular-errors.log" for further details.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! `ng serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @0.0.16 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

The problem is that this Angular project also has peer dependencies. I installed `npm-install-peers` package but it seems that simply running `npm install` afterwards will not install the required peer dependencies.
What should I do next to get this Angular project installed locally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is likely because angular cli or npm-peer-dependencies are not installed globally on your machine.
The steps that you should take are to make sure of them are globally installed.
To install packages globally you need run `npm install -g <package_name>`
[npm docs link](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally)

In your case for angular cli you should run
`npm i -g @angular/cli@11.2.15` and `npm install -g npm-peer-dependencies`.
Then run `npm start`.